# Sending extras to single activity from multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have set of activities like A, B, C, D. If A is the home activity, I want to send values through put Extras to activity A from different activities.

From B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("from_B", true);
startActivity(intent)
```

From C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("from_C", true);
startActivity(intent)
```

From D:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(D.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("from_D", true);
startActivity(intent)
```

In activity A:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        isCreate = (boolean) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("-----");
    }
```

Can someone help me what should I keep in the place of (------) in activity A in order to identify from which activity it is called

Comment: Rather than use shared preferences and use across all app :)

Comment: okay. What if I have to send different values.. for example integer from one activity, string from another and boolean from other. I'm new to this so i dont have idea about shared preferences.

Comment: Consider using intent.putExtra("from_activity","B"); or intent.putExtra("from_activity","C");

Comment: @Dyo who downvoted ?? let me know the reason..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In activity A, declare a String Tag :

```
public static final String    TAG_ACTIVITY_FROM = "WhichActivity";
```

In other activities, send :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(D.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra(A.TAG_ACTIVITY_FROM, "From_D");
startActivity(intent);
```

In A, get it back with :

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    String activityFrom = (String) getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_ACTIVITY_FROM);
}
```

EDIT : 
You can put as many extras as you want, such as (from Activity D)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(D.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra(A.TAG_ACTIVITY_FROM, "From_D");
intent.putExtra(A.VALUE, 4);
startActivity(intent);
```

With in Activity A :

```
public static final String VALUE = "value";

if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
  String activityFrom = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_ACTIVITY_FROM);
  int value = getIntent().getIntExtra(VALUE, -1);
}
```

Comment: so i should check if the activity is from B or C or D and accordingly I can get values from that activity??

Comment: See my edit, you can add as many extras as you want, such as an integer you want to pass, or text, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

use `startActivityForResult`

```
private static final int B = 1;
private static final int C = 2;
private static final int D = 3;

Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, B);
```

or:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityC.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, C);
```

or:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityD.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, D);


 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (requestCode == B)
            {
                boolean b = (boolean)data.getExtras().get("b");
            }
            if (requestCode == C)
            {
                boolean c = (boolean)data.getExtras().get("c");
            }
            if (requestCode == D)
            {
                boolean d = (boolean)data.getExtras().get("d");
            }
        }
    }
```

and in your B or C or D activity:

here is sample for B activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("b",true);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

From B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("NAVIGATION_TYPE", "Activity B");
startActivity(intent)
```

From C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("NAVIGATION_TYPE", "Activity C");
startActivity(intent)
```

From D:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(D.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("NAVIGATION_TYPE", "Activity D");
startActivity(intent)
```

In activity A:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
     String cmgString= getIntent().getStringExtra("NAVIGATION_TYPE");
    }
```

IF YOU WANT TO SENT INTEGER VALUE THEN SENT IT DIRECTLY AND RECEIVE IT USING getIntExtra.

Answer (score -1):

Pass One Extra Param to in activity and get in A

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(D.this, A.class);
    intent.putExtra("from_B", true);
    intent.putExtra("activity", "A");
    startActivity(intent);
```

in Second Activity

```
  if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        String from = (String)getIntent().getStringExtra("from_B");
        String fromActivity = (String)getIntent().getStringExtra("activity");
    }
```